# RuboCop style suggestion: "Pass '$:to_i' as an argument to 'Transform' instead of a block."

Tags: rubocop

I guess I'm not quite understanding the style suggestion.  I'm passing a regexp to Transform, is this considered a "block"?  And how do I pass $:key to Transform in this situation?

```
CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT = Transform(/^\$(\d+)$/) do |digits|
  digits.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] is this considered a "block"?

Anything wrapped in `do`-`end` is a block in Ruby.

> And how do I pass &:key to Transform in this situation?

Ruby implements `Symbol#to_proc` for you, to allow the shorthand `&:method` argument for block that send a single method to the yielded object.

In your case, this is equivalent:

```
CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT = Transform(/^\$(\d+)$/, &:to_i)
```